# sql joins - Joining more than one table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to understand joins and im a bit confused. I know how to join tables using

```
=
<=
```

IN 
   exists and not exists

I was trying to try and understand the use of INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, USING etc but it is so confusing. The major problem i am having is that different people refer to them using different names. Is there a simple explanation of the different types of joins and what other names they are known as. For example, while googling i came across the following types

```
♦ Simple Join
♦ Equi join
♦ Natural Join
♦ Outer Join
♦ Self Join
♦ Cartesian join
♦ Inner join
♦ Nonequi join
♦ Theta join
♦ Self join 
♦ Cross join
♦ Cross Joins
♦ Natural Joins
♦ Inner Join with USING Clause
♦ Inner Join with ON Clause
♦ Left Outer Join
♦ Right Outer Join
♦ Full OuterJoin
```

The majority of the above are duplicates, i.e. its the same type of join but with a different name. I am sure all the above can be recreated using one of (=, !=, not in, in exists etc) but I am struggling to undestand which is which and the difference between them. A diagram would probably help :)

Comment: Also, your list is kinda messy. I think it is safe to assume that *cross join* and *cross joins* refer to the same type of join. Same goes for *natural join* and *self join*.

Comment: Also, simple and inner joins are the same as well (http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some of the ones that weren't explained by Matthew's post:

Simple Join - A non explicit join, it defaults to an inner join

```
a join b on a.id = b.id
```

Natural Join - This does an inner join on all columns with the same name

```
a natural join b
```

Self Join - This is joining a table to itself, it can any other type of join (inner self join, outer self join, etc)

```
a "a1" join a "a2" on "a1".id = "a2".id
```

Cartesian join - This is every possible combination of rows, you'll always end up with the product of the number of rows from both tables.  You do it with an inner join without specifying a join condition

```
a join b
```

Cross join - This is a synonym for a Cartesian join

Inner Join with USING Clause - This is an alternate syntax for join conditions, you can use it if both tables have matching column names

```
a join b using (id)
```

Inner Join with ON Clause - This is the same as what I showed for a simple join, the only other syntax is to join in the where clause (as below)

```
a join b where a.id = b.id
```

Left Outer Join - Same as a left join
Right Outer Join - Same as a right join.  It's like a left join, but you get nulls on the first table rather than the second one

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. Is there a resource that shows the different syntax that can be used for the different types? for example the simple join is the same as an inner join and the difference is just syntax.

Comment: I don't know of one, no.  The problem is that it boils down to preference or company best practices, so sources will generally only show one of the several syntaxes.  If you're using Oracle, you can say that the words INNER and OUTER are optional.  There's also the "old" way, check out this link for a brief overview: http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/933-ANSI-Join-Syntax.html

Answer (score 11):

Jeff Atwood to the rescue

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 2):

by the way, just reading about JOIN. Something change on a MySQL Syntax? 
Oracle use PLSQL  syntax it is a little different from other databases..

I have the follow situation here

**Fisrt Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN (tbl2, tbl3, tbl4)
    ON (tbl2.field1=tbl1.field1 AND tbl3.filed2=tbl1.field2 AND tbl4.field3=tbl1.field3)
```

**Second Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN (tbl2 CROSS JOIN tbl3 CROSS JOIN tbl4)
    ON (tbl2.field1=tbl1.field1 AND tbl3.filed2=tbl1.field2 AND tbl4.field3=tbl1.field3)
```

The **Fisrt Query** is the same of **Second Query**.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Just came across http://www.gplivna.eu/papers/sql_join_types.htm which, although technical, provides a rather good overview of sql join types. Worth a look

Here is another page with some of the joins explained (http://blog.noobtech.com/index.php/2009/02/sql-joins-visual-cheat-sheet/)

The page I was just about to post was the one which @matthew vines already posted :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle SQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/queries006.htm#i2054012) has a good section on what joins are and the different join types.